# Pandas - Remove strings from a float number in a column

Tags: python, pandas, data-cleaning

I have a dataframe like the following:

```
plan type  hour status     code
A    cont   0    ok       010.0
A    cont   2    ok      025GWA
A    cont   0    notok   010VVT
A    cont   0    other     6.05
A    vend   1    ok        6.01
```

The column code has a few string characters with different letters. In the end I would like to transform the 'code' column to float.
I tried:

```
df['code'] = df['code'].str.extract('(\d+)').astype(float)
```

but with this I got:

```
plan type  hour status     code
A    cont   0    ok        10.0
A    cont   2    ok        25.0 
A    cont   0    notok     10.0
A    cont   0    other      6.0
A    vend   1    ok         6.0
```

How can I get a result like the following?

```
plan type  hour status     code
A    cont   0    ok       10.00
A    cont   2    ok       25.00
A    cont   0    notok    10.00
A    cont   0    other     6.05
A    vend   1    ok        6.01
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `(\d*\.?\d*)`

```
In [441]: df['code'].str.extract('(\d*\.?\d*)', expand=False).astype(float)
Out[441]:
0    10.00
1    25.00
2    10.00
3     6.05
4     6.01
Name: code, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I am having the same problem apart as I have `%` on the end of some of my floats, however it hasn't seemed to have removed it.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of than extraction, you could consider a substitution-based approach.

Use `str.replace`, and then convert to float with an `astype`/`to_numeric` conversion.

```
 df.code.str.replace('[^\d.]', '').astype(float)
```

Or,

```
pd.to_numeric(df.code.str.replace('[^\d.]', ''), errors='coerce')
```

```
0    10.00
1    25.00
2    10.00
3     6.05
4     6.01
Name: code, dtype: float64
```